# Clear stack of ViewControllers when Exit and Re-login

Tags: swift, navigation, exit

i've an app in swift 5, where i want to my user can logout, going to a login screen, so i created a menu with option "Logout". the option is working, but, when i logout and login again, instead of my "segue" leave to the main screen, leaves back to the option menu, where i was before. So, I need to, when I logout, clear my previous stack, to i don't go back to my Menu, previosly openned, when i re-login.

I tried to use dismiss method, uwind segue and popToRootViewController, but, or not worked, or they had a delay, and poped up my login screen, instead of my option menu.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
    }
```

Comment: What about performing a segue to the navigation controller once user logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `rootViewController` of the main window that lives inside the app delegate:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window!.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: did not worked. now, when i click "login", don't perform segue to main screen

Comment: This is how you set the initial view controller like the fresh app launch.